# What causes this external set of helper functions to fail in my React 18 app?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on an SPA with **React 18** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**.

I need to format dates nicely in this app. For this purpose I use Moment.js.

In `src\utils\datetime-formatter.ts` I have:

```
import moment from "moment";

function dataTimeFormatter() {

    const formatDateLong = (value) => {
        return moment(value).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    };

    const formatDateShort = (value) => {
        return moment(value).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
    };

    const yearsAgo = (value) => {
        return moment(value, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(true);
    }
    
}

export default dataTimeFormatter;
```

In the component I need to use it I have:

```
import dataTimeFormatter from "../../utils/datetime-formatter";

function Actordetails() {
    // More code
    
    return (
     <div className="row">
        {actor.birthday && actor.place_of_birth ?
          <p className="birth-info small">
            Born in <strong>{actor.place_of_birth}</strong>, on <strong>{formatDateLong(actor.birthday)}</strong>
          </p> : <></>
        }
     </div>
    );

}
```

#### The problem

The tewrminal shows this error (from Actordetails.jsx):

> 'formatDateLong' is not defined

From `datetime-formatter.js`, the erro is:

> 'formatDateLong' is assigned a value but never used

#### Questions

1. What is my mistake?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix the bug?

Comment: You should remove the `dataTimeFormatter` function (as it doesn't serve much of a purpose) and instead `export` each function inside it separately, then import the ones your need in your `Actordetails` component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three utility functions you've created only exist as local variables inside `dataTimeFormatter`. If someone were to call `dataTimeFormatter`, it would start running, create 3 local variables, and then finish running, at which point those 3 variables can be garbage collected.

You need to rewrite it so the functions are not local variables. There's a couple ways you could do this. For example, you could export the individual functions:

```
export const formatDateLong = (value) => {
  return moment(value).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
};

export const formatDateShort = (value) => {
  return moment(value).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
};

export const yearsAgo = (value) => {
  return moment(value, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(true);
};

// Used like:
import { formatDateLong } from "../../utils/datetime-formatter";
//...
<strong>{formatDateLong(actor.birthday)}</strong>
```

Or you could put the functions on an object and export that:

```
const dateTimeFormatter = {
  formatDateLong: (value) => {
    return moment(value).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
  },
  formatDateShort: (value) => {
    return moment(value).format("MMM DD, YYYY");
  },
  yearsAgo: (value) => {
    return moment(value, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(true);
  },
};

export default dateTimeFormatter

// used like
import dateTimeFormatter from "../../utils/datetime-formatter";
// ...
<strong>{dateTimeFormatter.formatDateLong(actor.birthday)}</strong>
```